# Mapping tables to classes

Tags: vb.net, design-patterns

If you have the following class:

```
Public Class Male
    Inherits Person

    Private Age As integer
    Private TelephoneNumber As String

End Class
```

and the following table

```
CREATE TABLE Person (ID int identity not null, Age int, TelephoneNumber varhchar(30), sex varhchar(6), primary key (ID))
```

In order to populate the Male class you would have to run an SQL statement, saying: WHERE Sex='MALE'.  Is this a poor design choice where one database table has two classes? i.e. there is a one to many relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is `Table per Class Hierarchy`, and is perfectly acceptable. This design pattern uses a single table to store multiple subclasses and uses a discriminator (in your case `Sex`) to distinguish between them.

Comment: Thanks, I am not using NHibernate.  Does the discriminator concept still apply?

Comment: In my case the discriminator column in the database contains about thirty distinct values.

Comment: NHibernate is just an ORM tool. The concept of ORM is not exclusive to NHibernate. The number of discriminator values that you have doesn't really matter. In fact, given that you have so many different types, I think you have chosen well. Otherwise, imagine having to maintain 30 separate tables!  You have the added advantage that if you need to add any more subclasses, you only need to come up with a new discriminator value and don't need a new table.

Comment: @w0051977 - If my answer/comments have been helpful, I'd appreciate an upvote or accepted answer. Or if you need more help, let me know.